# Autocomplete form once the name is enter PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I found a couple of similar questions but nothing with the same "variables" so here we go:

I have a simple form where I enter a name and I need the rest of the form to be completed automatically (ID).

Fetching the data in the DB is not an issue, I'm able to return Json using PHP (Search.php):

```
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM info_employer WHERE Prenom LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY Prenom ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = array( Nom => $row['Prenom'] . ' ' . $row['Nom'], Num => $row['Num'] );
}


//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

This give me an array that look like this:

```
[{"Nom":"Andre Nadeau","Num":"104J"},{"Nom":"Andre Potvin","Num":"130J"},{"Nom":"Andre Thibodeau","Num":"91J"}]
```

Friends told me that I should use Jquery and Ajax to use this array to fill my form but I have 2 issue.

First If I return an Array instead of "just the name" my autocomplete form don't work anymore. It give me X numbers of blank space (depending the number of results).

And of course my biggest problem is that i'm not able to send the ID (Num) in the form

Javascript i'm using to autocomplete the name :

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#Nom" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'Search.php',
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: **source** param expects a simple array while you are passing a multi dimensional array to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the return object to make it match the spec [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

```
$data[] = array( "label" => $row['Prenom'] . ' ' . $row['Nom'], "value" => $row['Num'] );
```

This should result in an array of objects with a 'label' and 'value' key. This will work with your autocomplete.

Comment: This is not labeling my values ?

Comment: $data[] = array( Nom => $row['Prenom'] . ' ' . $row['Nom'], Num => $row['Num'] );

Comment: Just to be clear, "Nom" use 2 row and "Num" is the row containing the ID

Comment: Read the link I posted. Your dataset you pass into the autocomplete MUST match what they're expecting. You either pass an array of strings, an array of objects with a "label" and "value", a URL that has GET values posted to it, or a specialized callback to hook up to your datasource.

It's easier to just change the array keys in PHP to match this.

Comment: I read the link and I still having trouble understanding what i need to change here:

    {"Nom":"Andre Nadeau","Num":"104J"}

"Nom" is my label and "Andre Nadeau" is my value ? For me its look like everything is labelled correctly ? Do I have to use the exact term "Label" and "Value" ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use those exact keys. Autocomplete doesn't understand french keys yet.

Comment: Hey first I just want to thank you for your time, I really appreciate it. 

This solve half of my problem. Using the right keys my autocomplete work to find a Name but when I select it, the name is replaced with the ID in the same field. My goal is to send the ID (value) in another field. If you have any link to point me in the right direction :)